# How to represent repeating character in NFA/DFA

Tags: c#, state-machine

I am in the process of writing a parser to parse a structured text file containing UN EDIFACT codes list.  To do this I have written a generic state machine in C# that I want to use to create the parser.

One problem I am having is how do I correctly match a sequence of 70 dashes?  Do I need to increment a counter of some sort each time a dash is encountered and then process whatever action is necessary?  I haven't been able to find anywhere that explains how to do this.

This is a snapshot of the text file I am trying to parse:

```
PART 5    UNITED NATIONS DIRECTORIES FOR ELECTRONIC DATA INTERCHANGE
          FOR ADMINISTRATION, COMMERCE AND TRANSPORT

CHAPTER 6 Code list

1.   Code list UNCL

     Change indicators

     a plus sign (+)    for an addition
     an asterisk (*)    for an addition/subtraction/change to an entry
                        for a particular data element
     a hash sign (#)    for changes to names
     a vertical bar (|) for changes to text for descriptions,
                        notes and functions
     a letter X (X)     for marked for deletion

     Usage indicators

     [B] = used in batch messages only
     [I] = used in interactive messages only
     [C] = common usage in both batch and interactive messages

----------------------------------------------------------------------

*    1001  Document name code                                      [C]

     Desc: Code specifying the document name.

     Repr: an..3

     1     Certificate of analysis
              Certificate providing the values of an analysis.

     2     Certificate of conformity
              Certificate certifying the conformity to predefined
              definitions.
```

Comment: Not getting you? Do you want How to represent NFA/DFA in Text file?

Comment: No.  I want to know how to represent a repeating character in a state machine.  The file I am parsing uses 70 dashes in sequence to separate each code list from it's data element.  The only way I can do this is by creating 70 states for each dash.  There has to be a more efficient way than doing this.

Comment: can't use a different character to represent 70 dashes?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by using a different character? I am reading a file character by character and when it hits the dash character it loops back onto the same state.  I am trying to figure out how to determine whether 70 dashes have been found?

Comment: Sorry Mike, better is to put some  snapshot of your text file in Question!

Comment: I have amended by question to include the first few lines of the text file I am trying to parse.

Comment: I think I can understood you problem!... yes you are correct you have to loops back onto the same state for hashes ans as soon as you get symbol other than dash you should switch to other state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parsing is usually done on two distinct levels of abstraction. On a lower level a lexical parser detects basic tokens like words, numbers, parentheses and so on. On a higher level a syntactical parser analyses the syntax. The syntactical analysis works with those abstract tokens and does not look at single characters.

The lexical parser works in a simple, primitive way using loops and counters for instance. This is how I would detect the separators made of dashes.

The state machine should be based on the tokens and implement the syntactical analysis.

See [Compiler Construction - N. Wirth](http://www.ethoberon.ethz.ch/WirthPubl/CBEAll.pdf) at [Oberon Bibliography](http://www.ethoberon.ethz.ch/books.html)

Comment: Actually, I find it entirely reasonable to detect the dash separator as *one* token. Logically, at least, that’s how it should be. Unfortunately, the size of this token will blow up the state machine which may lead to technical problems, depending on the implementation (e.g. when the transition function is implemented as a matrix).

Comment: @Oliver: +1 for this as this is probably the best way to go.  Bear in mind that everything before the first set of 70 dashes will be used as comments, so I could write a lexer that will capture everything until the first set of 70 dashes and store these comments in a _COMMENTS_ token for example, and this can then be processed by the syntax parser.  Does that sound right?

Comment: @Mike Clarke: Yes, either the comments are skipped and ignored by the lexical parser, or if you need them at some point then pack them into a comments token.

Comment: @Konrad Rudolph: I would not implement the lexical parser with a state machine. I would use loops, switch statements and counters. The state machine should see the separator line as a single token, not as 70 dashes! Therefore the 70 dashes will never blow the state machine.

Comment: @Olivier That would still be a state machine, albeit hard-coded. And that’s almost never a good idea. I’ve done it myself plenty of times but it’s madness, since every single change in the grammar potentially requires a fundamental rewrite (manual state machines aren’t open to general modifications).

Comment: @Konrad Rudolph,  Mike Clarke: I suggest dividing the task into two separate tasks. The lower level task (lexical parsing) is hard coded and yields tokens (It could be represented by a method `Token GetNextToken()`). The higher level task (syntactical analysis, grammar/structure analysis) is implemented as a (soft coded) state machine. Changes in grammar only affect the high level, not the low level. Tokens can be represented as classes or as an enum plus a string.

Comment: @Olivier Token definitions can change, too. That’s what I was referring to. It’s generally not beneficial to hard-code the token scanner, unless you are after ultimate performance. On the other hand, regex-based token scanners are orders of magnitude smaller (in SLOC) much less complex, and as a consequence easier to debug and adapt.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes: You didn't mention whether I should read the file one character as a time or one whole line?  Would I also need to consider looking n-characters ahead to see if 70 dashes have been encountered, just in case the lexer encounters dashes with the comments section?

Comment: Usually you will use a line buffer, i.e., read one line into a string and then do the character processing on that string. Read the comment lines without doing any further analysis until you encounter one line with only dashes.

Comment: Does that would mean I would need to maintain state to keep track of whether I am in a comment or a data element (this actually follows the 70 dashes)?

Comment: It depends how the comment section is introduced. If there is a simple way to detect the beginning of it (like a line starting with the word "PART" or maybe the comments are always at the beginning of the file) then the lexical parser can do this "on the fly" without having to keep state of anything.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes: I am accepting your answer as I have decided to use your suggestion of breaking the process into 2 separate layers.  I have managed to create a lexical analyzer that yields tokens which will be sent to the syntax analyzer using Rx to improve performance.  Thanks again for the input!

Answer (score 0):

NFAs cannot count. In order to represent repeating characters you have to introduce one state per character:

```
╭───╮    -    ╭───╮    -    ╭───╮          ╭────╮
│ 0 │ ──────> │ 1 │ ──────> │ 2 │ ── ⋯ ──> │ 70 │
╰───╯         ╰───╯         ╰───╯          ╰────╯
```

… Of course, you could instead augment your engine by some kind of counter variable. But then it’s no longer a direct representation of a DFA (or NFA).

Comment: That is a scenario I was trying to avoid.  However, in addition to Oliver's answer this is also a possible solution to be considered.